# Creation new Typescript datatype by extending existing

Tags: arrays, typescript

I want to create a new Datatype by extending the existing `Array`.

Here is an example of an extension:

```
interface Array<T> {
    Count(): number;
}

Array.prototype.Count = function() {
    return this.length;
}
```

What worries me  is messing with the existing Datatype. Is there a way to  create a new Datatype with the new Datatype an extension of the `Array`?

Lets call it `List<T>` for example. Where `List` is an `Array` with the `Count()` method.

I have looked at `Class List<T> extends Array<T>` but that does not work. Any suggestions?

**Update 2016-04**

With the new updates to TypeScript, I gave it another shot...

Current implementation:

```
class List<T> extends Array<T> {
    private _items: Array<T> = [];
    constructor(items: Array<T>) {
        super();
        this._items = items;
    }
    public where(filter: any, ...arg): Array<T> {
        return this._items.filter(item => filter(item, ...arg));
    }
}
```

Following works:

```
 interface IItem {
        name: string
   }

   let items = Array<IItem> = [];

   // add few 'item's to items.    

   let list = new List<IItem>(items);
   let filter = (item: IItem, name: string) => { return item.name === name };
   let filteredList = list.where(filter, name);
```

Would like to get this working:

```
let list = List<IItem> = [];

// add few 'item's to items.    

let filter = (item: IItem, name: string) => { return item.name === name };
let filteredList = list.where(filter, name);
```

Compiler Error:

```
[ts] Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'List<IItem>'.
Property '_items' is missing in type 'undefined[]'.
```

am I missing something?

Comment: @Sohnee, any suggestion? see updated section above.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a way that is a bit hacky now, but that will let you easily replace the implementation when sub-classing native types arrives.

The set up looks like this...

```
interface IList<T> extends Array<T> {
    count(): number;
}


var ListShim = function() {
    this.count = () => {
        return this.length;
    }
}
ListShim.prototype = new Array();

class List<T> {
    static create<T>() : IList<T> {
        return <IList<T>> new ListShim();
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
var list = List.create<string>();

list.push('test a');
console.log(list.count());
console.log(list[0]);

list.push('test b');
console.log(list.count());
console.log(list[1]);
```

Later on, if you find you can sub-class the native type (i.e. all your browsers allow it) you can replace the implementation without changing your calling code.

```
interface IList<T> extends Array<T> {
    count(): number;
}

class List<T> extends Array<T> {
    static create<T>() : IList<T> {
        return new List();
    }

    count() {
        return this.length;
    }
}
```

This last code block is "a stab in the dark" as I don't know what this will really look like, but you should be insulated from the exact details by your `create` factory method.

Comment: Great! Works like a dream... One stupid question: Why is it not possible to replace `var ListShim = function()...` with `var ListShim = () => ...` @Steve

Comment: @FlippieCoetser because then it would use the value of `this` found outside the function—`this` would not equal the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Sub-classing built-in types is coming with ES2015 (aka ES6/Harmony), but no browser has the feature enabled by default right now (see [compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Array_is_subclassable)).

Your only option right now is to use some prototype hacking...